# Is there a way to mark a project in eclipse if a CVS Update is pending?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

when i startup eclipse, first thing i usually do is updating my source code to pull in changes from other developers (or from my home work). Sometimes i just forget it. But as we are usually working in a small team on HEAD, we all usually want to have the latest sources.

It would be nice to let eclipse automatically (like every hour or so), synchronize its workspace with CVS server and mark the project with a label for pending updates (of course it shoul dnot update the source code automatically!)

I have searched the web for it and i found some comments on CVS watch/edit feature. But i don't like to call edit every time i work on a file and i don't want to be informed by mail. All i need is a little icon at my project which says "You might run cvs update before you work on".

Is something like this available as a feature in eclipse?

regards
Janning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you're asking for is precisely what the CVS watch/edit feature is for. I agree that the emailing issue is a major PiTA but hey - remember - CVS is quite old; many CVS concepts appear a bit odd nowadays, whereas they appeared more reasonable when CVS was first written.

I cannot think of any internal, Eclipse-provided way to do what you're asking. You basically need the "Synchronize" view to be updated periodically - and, the way that the CVS plugins are written - that view is only populated upon startup and whenever you select "synchronize with repository".

Isaac

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. But i am wondering why no one has written such an extension to the eclipse/cvs plugin. i mean it is just triggering "cvs -nq upd -dP" every 10 minutes and mark the project if some updates are pending.

Comment: ... Be my (our) guest. Let us know when it's done so we can all enjoy it. :-) Actually, one of my clients has the need for something similar at the moment; I may write my own plugin to do that.